# Investigating a function with a parameter

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

I got stuck on solving this problem:

**For which $a \in \Bbb R$ is the function**
$$
    f_a: \ ]1, \ \infty[ \; \longrightarrow \ \Bbb R: x\mapsto \frac{\log x}{(x-1)^a} 
$$
**continuous on $[1, \ \infty[$ ? How should the value of $\ f_a(1)$ be chosen in these cases?**

The point is obviously to observe what happens to function at $x = 1$. But from my view the function is not continuos in this point independent of the choice of $a$ as, when $x=1$ the denominator turns $0$. The condition by which the function is continuous at certain point is defined by $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = f(x)$. However I can't see how $f(1)$ could exist.

I've plotted the function in *Mathematica* and received the following image for $a$ even:
[image: a=2]

Can't figure out where this vertical at $x=1$ comes from. What should be a proper way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f_a(x)=\dfrac{\log x}{(x-1)}\cdot\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^{a-1}}.$$

There you go.

- When $a\lt1$ the limit is as follow: $$\lim_{x\to1^+}f_a(x)=0=f_a(1).$$
- When $a=1$ the limit is as follow: $$\lim_{x\to1^+}f_a(x)=1=f_a(1).$$
- When $a\gt1$ the limit is as follow: $$\lim_{x\to1^+}f_a(x)=+\infty.$$

P.S. $$\lim_{x\to1^+}\dfrac{\log x}{x-1}=1.$$

Comment: Still don't get how you define $f_a(1) = 0$. Could you explain why the denominator is kind of ignored in this case? Seems to me that $f_a(1) = \frac{\log 1}{(1-1)^a} = \frac 00 $ doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah now I see that's for $a<1$ when it goes to numerator.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f_a$ is continuous on $1 \leq x \leq \infty$ for all $a \leq 0$ and in all cases where $f_a$ is continuous $f_a(1)$ should be chosen as zero.

Comment: Could you explain why $f_a(1)$ should be chosen as $0$?